# How is the pointer changing?

Tags: c++, pointers

I cant find an explanation to why the pointer is changing in the below code.

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node *left;
    node *right;
}*root;

int main() {

    node *tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
    tmp->val = 5;
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
    root = tmp;


    node *t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
    cout<<"earlier: "<<&root->right<<" "<<root->right<<endl;
    t->val = 4;
    cout<<"after: "<<&root->right<<" "<<root->right<<endl;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    root->left = t;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is -

```
earlier: 0x7fb812404ac0 0x0
after: 0x7fb812404ac0 0x4
```

The value of `root->right` has changed and it is no longer `NULL`.

Note - I get this error in my OSX g++ compiler

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

It works as expected on other versions of g++ as shown at http://ideone.com/tIEjU4

What am I missing?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(node *))` that's wrong. If you're using C++, might as well use C++ features - `new` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like undefined behavior because you are writing into unallocated memory with a too-small allocation on both of the following lines.

```
node *tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
node *t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
```

Instead, you need to allocate enough for a node.

```
node *tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
node *t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

As the @Mat pointed out though, you probably want to use `new` here since you've tagged the question `c++`.

```
node *tmp = new node;
node *t = new node;
```

Comment: Usually, it's just the target architecture. If 32-bits, pointers will be 32 bits. If 64-bits, pointers will be 64 bits. (The exception would be pointers to class member functions, since they need a `this` offset as well.)

Comment: A common technique in C to avoid allocating a wrong size using `malloc()` is of the form `node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp))` (assuming one object being allocated).   That works in C++ too, except for the need to do a `(node *)` type conversion.   But, as Mat pointed out, better to use C++ facilities (operator `new`) in this case.